# bootstrap datepicker highlight two dates

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

In bootstrap date-picker i want to highlight two dates.I can able to highlight two dates but unable to differentiate the two date by color or some class it apply same blue color for both dates can any one help

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src ="Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" >
       $(document).ready(function () {
       var DD = "29";
       var MM = "04";
       var YY = "2014";
       var CaseDD = "25";
       var CaseMM = "04";
       var CaseYY = "2014";

  $('#calendar').datepicker({
               format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
               multidate: true,
               multidateSeparator: "/",
               autoclose: true,
               showOtherMonths: true,
               dayNamesMin: ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"],
               beforeShowDay: highlightDays()
           });
           $('#calendar').datepicker('setDate', new Date(YY, MM, DD), new Date(CaseYY, CaseMM, CaseDD));
       });
```

```
        <div class="container">
       <div id="calendar" style="margin-left:-10px;border:1px solid  #E1E1E1;width:203px;"> </div>
   </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: add your html as well!

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a bit late, but I found this question while trying to solve the same problem.

The simplest way I found to do this was to apply a separate class to each day that pops up, and then use that class to highlight the days I wanted. 
The "beforeShowDay" option of datepicker allows you to return a string that gets added as a class to each date () element that appears.
getMonth() is 0-indexed so we add 1 to it.

If I wasn't lazy, it would probably make more sense to extend the datepicker with a method that would allow for such functionality.

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
   fulldate = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate();
   console.log(fulldate);
   return fulldate;
} 
//you can now reference individual date td date segments as $("2018-5-30")
//you can also modify the code above to only apply the class to the dates you want, or change what class you apply
```